# Website or text book for sound

Tags: acoustics, resource-recommendations

I'm a phd student in an engineering department.
I need to research about sound created by fluid flow with sand in a pipe.
From my image, the sound is made by the turbulence of fluid and the physical effect of sand.
But I've not learned about sound physics and I'm not sure how to consider about it theoretically.
Would you tell me a text or a website that I can learn about basics about sound physics?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Your question is a "resource recommendation" question, so you may want to consult our [guidance on such questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed) and edit your question if you can see ways to improve it.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know that. Thank you Michael!